# Averaging and removing list values

Tags: list-manipulation, image-processing

So I'm trying to generate an interpolation function from a bode plot (log-log plot) by extracting the graph data using mathematica. I've got to the point where I was able to isolate only the curve I am interested in (black/white image), and generate a list of points from there. However, my list has a few y-values for each x-value, and so the interpolation function does not work. I want to average these values and compress them into a single point.

My list is of the form

```
exampleList={{10, 100}, {10, 1000}, {15, 200} ... }
```

and what I want is

```
newList={{10, 550}, {15, 200} ... }
```

where 550 is the arithmetic mean of 100 and 1000.

I'm a C programmer and I could write the whole thing with a couple of Do[] and If[]'s, but I'm trying to learn how to use Mathematica, not C.

[image: Bode plot for gain and phase][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possible approaches for doing that:

- [`SequenceCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceCases.html) (for a first-element sorted list):

  ```
  SequenceCases[exampleList, {args : {x_, _} ..} :> {x, Mean[{args}[[All, 2]]]}]
  ```
- [`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) and [`KeyValueMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KeyValueMap.html):

  ```
  (* a first possibility *)
  KeyValueMap[{#1, Mean[#2]} &, GroupBy[exampleList, First -> Last]]

  (* equivalent *)
  KeyValueMap[{#1, #2} &, GroupBy[exampleList, First -> Last, Mean]]
  ```

Comment: SequenceCases[] worked like a charm! The notation is still a little opaque to me, though. What's the purpose of using a delayed rule here?

Comment: It avoids the evaluation of the right-hand side. This is in particular useful if `x` and `args` where defined elsewhere during the same session. For instance, you can try: `x = 3; args = {0, 
  0}; SequenceCases[exampleList, {args : {x_, _} ..} -> {x, 
   Mean[{args}[[All, 2]]]}]`, and the same with `RuleDelayed`. Using the latter, you make sure that these two arguments are bound to the left-hand side of the rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}}
```

Then

```
lst // GroupBy[First] // KeyValueMap[ {#1, N@Mean@#2[[All, 2]]} &]
```

or

```
GatherBy[lst, First] // Map[{#[[1, 1]], N@Mean@#[[All, 2]]} &]
```

both return

```
(* {{1, 1.5}, {2, 2.5}} *)
```